# Can't update database table's column using trigger or from php page but works after using update sql query in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

After inserting into my audit log table called `userUpdateLog`and it calls an before insert trigger to insert into `userProfiles` and `users` based off the columns insert into their respective table.

but for an column, `nickName` that I added after the `userProfiles` table was created and have data, it doesn't update via trigger using the query or from the php page using the same query(with variables instead of NEW.newNickName and New.userID).

```sql
    UPDATE userProfiles 
       SET nickName = NEW.newNickName 
     WHERE userID = NEW.userID
```

However, if I tried it via phpMyAdmin and execute the query, it works

```sql
    UPDATE userProfiles 
       SET nickName = 'random' 
     WHERE userID = 2
```

Now if I used the php page or trigger statement, it will update the row where userID = 2, but for other rows, the same issue as I had in the beginning still.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `userUpdateLog` (
  `userUpdateLogID` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `userID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updateDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `newUserName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newEmail` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newNickName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newFirstName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newLastName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldUserName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldEmail` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldNickName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldFirstName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldLastName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `usersUpdate_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `userUpdateLog` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @userName = (SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET @email = (SELECT email FROM users WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET @firstName = (SELECT firstName FROM users WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET @lastName = (SELECT lastName FROM users WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET @nickName = (SELECT nickName FROM userProfiles WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET NEW.oldUserName = @userName;
    SET NEW.oldEmail = @email;
    SET NEW.oldFirstName = @firstName;
    SET NEW.oldLastName = @lastName; 
    SET NEW.oldNickName = @nickName;
    IF NEW.newUserName IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newUserName <> NEW.oldUserName THEN
        UPDATE users 
        SET userName = NEW.newUserName 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.newEmail IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newEmail <> NEW.oldEmail THEN
        UPDATE users 
        SET email = NEW.newEmail 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.newFirstName IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newFirstName <> NEW.oldFirstName THEN
        UPDATE users 
        SET firstName = NEW.newFirstName 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID; 
    END IF;
    IF NEW.newLastName IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newLastName <> NEW.oldLastName THEN
        UPDATE users 
        SET lastName = NEW.newLastName 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.newNickName IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newNickName <> NEW.oldNickName THEN
        UPDATE userProfiles SET nickName = NEW.newNickName 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE `userProfiles` (
  `profileID` int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imgName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nickName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aboutUser` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `genderID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `bDay` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `favCard` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userID` int(11) PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(128) UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `loginDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `userCreate` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO userProfiles (userID) VALUES(NEW.userID);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

for columns (genderID, bDay and favCard) all works; have yet to test out aboutUser column, I believe I encounter similar issue with imgName, a column which was also added after creation of the table, which I stopped using the column.

I also tried adding a new column into the table called `nick_name` and try to insert via trigger/php page no luck as well.

I've also tried creating a new table with same columns, and same userIDs called `usersProfiles` and attempt to using the same trigger to insert into the column, nickName, it doesn't work but works fine inserting into `users` table.

Any help would be great or is there something to do with optimizing table or something I am unaware of? Thanks in advance!

Comment: your first create table has a minor  error and with this information we can't without major work reproduce your error see if you can edit this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9666086d5cfe757ce255150da253cd15

Comment: sorry I did not provide `users` table, ill do that now

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but its not really a solution solution so hoping someone can shed some light on what the issue and how to fix it.

I changed the `nickName` column from being `DEFAULT NULL` to `DEFAULT "N/A" NOT NULL`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE userProfiles 
CHANGE 'nickName' 'nickName' varchar(128) 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci 
DEFAULT NULL;
```

to:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `userProfiles` 
CHANGE `nickName` `nickName` VARCHAR(128) 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci 
NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A';
```

then the columns work and any new row inserted as well.

However if I change it back to `DEFAULT NULL` the same issue occur again.